# POST http://localhost/sip/ess/public/attendance/savepresence 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel, post, internal-server-error

I'm trying to submit data to the database. I've changed the route to "get" or "post", but I'm getting this error:

I'm trying to submit data to the database. I've changed the route to "get" or "post", but I'm getting this error:

```
POST http://localhost/sip/ess/public/attendance/savepresence 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What's wrong with my code? Is it the route or the controller?

Route

```
Route::post('savepresence', 'Attendance@savepresence')->name('attendance.savepresence');
```

Controller

```
public function savepresence(Request $req)
    {
        $row    = Attendance::find($req->input('ap_id'));
        $rowEmp = Employee::find($row->emp_id);
      
        //SO 26-02-2023 Att RAW In
        $ar_time_in     = substr($req->input('ap_in'),11,8); 
        $ar_time_in_old = substr($row->ap_in,11,8);
        if (!empty($req->input('ap_in')) && $ar_time_in != $ar_time_in_old){
            Attendance_raw_tmp::create([
                    'emp_id'            => $row->emp_id,
                    'ar_date_tmp'       => $thisDate,
                    'ar_id_tmp'         => $rowEmp->emp_code,
                    'ar_time_tmp'       => $ar_time_in,
                    'ar_lat'            => '-6.3013773',
                    'ar_long'           => '106.8429748',
                    'ar_client_tmp'     => $req->input('ar_client_tmp'),
                    'ar_notes_tmp'      => $req->input('ar_notes_tmp'),
                    'ar_opid'           => $this->_user->user_id
                ]);
        }
        //SO 26-07-2022 Att RAW Out
        $ar_time_out     = substr($req->input('ap_out'),11,8); 
        $ar_time_out_old = substr($row->ap_out,11,8);
        if (!empty($req->input('ap_out')) && $ar_time_out != $ar_time_out_old){
           Attendance_raw_tmp::create([
                    'emp_id'            => $row->emp_id,
                    'ar_date_tmp'       => $thisDate,
                    'ar_id_tmp'         => $rowEmp->emp_code,
                    'ar_time_tmp'       => $ar_time_out_old,
                    'ar_lat'            => '-6.3013773',
                    'ar_long'           => '106.8429748',
                    'ar_client_tmp'     => $req->input('ar_client_tmp'),
                    'ar_notes_tmp'      => $req->input('ar_notes_tmp'),
                    'ar_opid'           => $this->_user->user_id
                ]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('attendance.index')->with('notif', [
            'type'      => 'success',
            'message'   => 'Update Attendance Submission has been saved.'
        ]);

    }
```

View

```
<div class="container attendancereview-form">
    <form action="{{ route('attendance.savepresence') }}" method="post" id="attendancereview-form" class="form-horizontal">
        @csrf
        
        <input type="hidden" name="ap_id" value="{{ $row->ap_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="emp_id" value="{{ $row->emp_id }}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group mb-4 row">
                    <label for="ap_date" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input class="form-control" name="ap_date" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $row->ap_date }}" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-4 row">
                    <label for="ap_in" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Time In </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input class="form-control" name="ap_in" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $row->ap_in }}" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss">
                            <font color="red">example : {{ $row->ap_date }} 08:00:00 </font>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-4 row">
                    <label for="ap_out" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Time Out </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input class="form-control" name="ap_out" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $row->ap_out }}" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss">
                            <font color="red">example : {{ $row->ap_date }} 17:00:00 </font>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-4 row">
                    <label for="client" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Client </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                       <input class="form-control" name="ar_client_tmp" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-4 row">
                    <label for="notes" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Notes </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                       <input class="form-control" name="ar_notes_tmp" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Please Help Me?

Comment: Add logs to know where it crashes and throws 500.

Comment: Try to change APP_ENV=local and APP_DEBUG=true for viewing the errors and kindly post it as well